# Trying to aggregate column values in eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-5, eloquent

I have model called Organisation, which has a many to one relationship with a model called Client, it looks like this,

```
public function clients() {
    return $this->hasMany('Client', 'owner_id')->orderBy('name', 'asc');
}
```

Client has a one to many relationship with projects that looks like this,

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Project');
}
```

The project model / table as a column called `total_cost` within an organisation I can gets it's clients, and then the clients projects, what I wanting to do is get the value of the client by aggregating all the clients projects `total_cost` entries, I am trying to do this with the following,

```
public function clientsValue() {
    return $this->clients()->projects()->select(DB::raw("SUM(total_cost) as client_value"));
}
```

In my mind this getting the projects through the clients relationship and then running a select on the project model, however I am getting the following error,

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::projects()
```

But I am not sure why as the clients has a projects relationship.

Answer (score 0):

**$this->clients()** returns relation definition - object of class **HasMany**, not a **Client** object. **HasMany** class does not have a **projects()** method, that's why you're getting an error.

In order to calculate total clients value, you first need to define additional relation between organization and projects:

```
public function projects() {
  return $this->hasManyThrough('Project', 'Client');
}
```

This will tell Eloquent how to fetch projects for given organization using intermediate **Client** model.

Once you have the relation you can call aggregate functions on it:

```
public function clientsValue() {
  return $this->projects()->sum('total_cost');
}
```

You can read more about aggregate functions here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#aggregates

You can read more about **hasManyThrough** relations here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through